# How to stop a promise chain when using $state.go() in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a chain of promises that are responsible for initializing my controller. In this chain if a certain condition isn't met, it would be best to send the user to another state via `$state.go()` and stop the rest of the promise chain from running. How can this be accomplished?

`loadData1()
    .then(function(){
      return loadData2();
    })
    .then(function(){
      if (...) {
        $state.go(...); // how should the existing promise chain be killed off or stopped?
      }
      else {
        return loadData3();
      }
    })
    .then(function(){
      return loadData4();
    })
    .then(function(){
      console.log('controller initialized successfully');
    },
    function(error){
      console.log('failed to initialize controller');
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of immediately calling `$state.go`, throw an error and check for it in the error handler at the end.

```
loadData1()
.then(function () {
  return loadData2();
})
.then(function () {
  if (exceptionalCondition) {
    throw new Error('[MyCtrl:loadData2] Data failed to load!');
  }
  return loadData3();
})
...
.then(function () {
  console.log('controller initialized successfully');
},
function (error) {
  if (/^\[MyCtrl:loadData2\]/.test(error.message)) {
    $state.go(redirect);
  } else {
    console.log('failed to initialize controller');
  }
});
```

The nice thing about using promises is that they will handle errors and immediately terminate the chain if one occurs.